# Inside the form action is not accepting "http url or custom url" in Accelerated Mobile Pages Project

Tags: php, html, accelerated-mobile-page

When we go to Accelerated Mobile Pages Project but inside the form action is not accepting "http url or custom url" lilke below :

```
<form method="post"
      **action="http://example.com"**   action-xhr="http://httpbin.org/response-headers"    target="_blank">
         <input type="title" name="term" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Acknowledge please.
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Invalid URL protocol 'http:' for attribute 'action' in tag 'form'.

Comment: You are trying to send the form data to another webpage? the form is submitting to a file, not a page. If you want to send data to another webpage/site you should check `curl`

Comment: The action attribute has to point to a script like `action="http://www.example.com/code/doit.php` or am I behind some new curve here?

Comment: the thing is your code works as a redirect... insert a term in the search box and you are redirected to it `http://example.com/?term=etete`... this is what you want ?

Comment: Actually we have need to submit and redirect to action url

Comment: It is working. Just delete the **...

Comment: ** is just was focus on action in my code ** is not write but not working

Comment: This is not a simple html code.........
 this is AMP code